# Can I include the Ubuntu Fonts in a proprietary application?

Tags: licensing, font

I am creating a desktop application that has the ability to generate PDF reports. I would like to use ubuntu font because it has wide language support. I do not plan to modify the font file in any way. Does the [license](https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/font-licence) allow that? It seems to me it does.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Ubuntu Font License seems to be an open source license and does allow use in proprietary applications. The Ubuntu Font License is based on the OSI-approved SIL Open Font License, but removes terms that create a pseudo-trademark and removes terms that gives the original authors of the font a special role.

A number of conditions apply if you propagate the font, here's the TL;DR:

- You must include copyright notices and the full license text with the font. However, these may be included in font metadata.
- If you do not modify the font, you must not rename the font.
- The font itself is always covered by this license, you cannot add your own (proprietary) licensing terms. However, documents created with this font are not subject to the license.

For desktop software, just attribute the bundled font as you would attribute any other included libraries: in a “help” or “about” menu entry, or where you provide your own copyright notices, also provide a list of all included open source works with their copyright notices and licenses. E.g. see web browsers like Chrome or Firefox for inspiration on how to do this.